# What is the best way to pass information between threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I want to be listening to a server while my program is doing other things, when a message is received from the server I want to interpret it.

I know about threading but not sure completely on how it works. If I have a thread listening for the server how can I pass that data to the main thread for interpretation? What is the best way for the main thread to send data to the server? What is the use of the synchronized modifier?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063159/sharing-data-between-threads

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> If I have a thread listening for the server how can I pass that data to the main thread for interpretation? What is the best way for the main thread to send data to the server?

I'd use a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) for this.  You define a single `BlockingQueue` such as the [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html).  Your listener class then calls `queue.take()` which will wait for your server to call `queue.put()`.  It leaves all of the synchronization, waits, notifies, etc. to the Java class instead of your own code.

> What is the use of the synchronized modifier?

I'd do some reading to understand more about this.  This is not the sort of thing that can be answered in a short-ish SO response.  The [Java concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) is a good place to start.

Comment: If the server is remote I should be listening on the socket on a new thread. Then when a message is received add it to the queue. Then have the main program check the queue and decide how to interpret the received message. Correct?

Comment: Something like that should work.  Or you can use RMI to put the message in the remote queue.  That removes the need to do the socket code.  See: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html

Answer (score 9):

If you want synchronous communication between a main thread and a processing thread, you can use a [SynchronousQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html).

The idea is that the main thread passes data to the processing thread by calling `put()`, and the processing thread calls `take()`. Both are blocking operations.

Note that if you want to send back a result, then things may get a bit more complex as the main thread has to know when the result is ready. A [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) is a good primitive for this. You can do something like this.

First let's define a datastructure to pass data around:

```
public class MethodCall {

    public final String methodName;

    public final Object[] args;

    public final CountDownLatch resultReady;

    public Object result;

    public MethodCall(String methodName, Object[] args) {
        this.methodName = methodName;
        this.args = args;
        this.resultReady = new CountDownLatch(1);
    }

    public void setResult(Object result) {
        this.result = result;
        resultReady.countDown();
    }

    public Object getResult() throws InterruptedException {
        resultReady.await();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Define the queue to pass data around, visible by both threads:

```
public SynchronousQueue<MethodCall> methodCalls = new SynchronousQueue<MethodCall>();
```

To make a call from the main thread to the processing thread and wait for the result:

```
MethodCall call = new MethodCall(methodName, args);
methodCalls.put(call);
Object result = call.getResult();
```

In the processing thread, for instance in a `run()` method, you can then do:

```
for (;;) {
    MethodCall call = methodCalls.take();
    Object res = processStuff(call.methodName, call.args);
    call.setResult(res);
}
```

Where `processStuff` implements your logic. Of course you should deal with exceptions as well, deal with exit cases, change `MethodCall` to have more specific things than `methodName` and `args` and an `Object` return, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Go through some tutorials for understanding Java Threads.

http://www.journaldev.com/1079/java-thread-tutorial

Your problem seems to be like producer-consumer model, you can use BlockingQueue to achieve this task easily.

[Java Blocking Queue](http://www.journaldev.com/1034/java-blockingqueue-example-implementing-producer-consumer-problem)

Comment: Most basic answer on Stackoverflow. 5 upvotes after 10 years speaks for itself.