# Return result of thread to a separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading

For example if I have thread A and thread B. Thread A is my main thread where most of the application runs but when I need a value fetched from MySQL or another external source I create a new thread (thread B).

What is the best way of returning the value from thread B to thread A for further processing without causing thread A to wait until the value is available?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148422/what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-information-between-threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a single task that needs to be done, you can use a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) and have the other Thread poll the (non-blocking) `isDone()` method whenever it is convenient.

If that task is executed frequently or you have many tasks to execute, using a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) might be a better idea, which also comes in a variant that supports blocking till a result is delivered as [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html). Again: polling on the list whenever it is convenient will do the trick.

If you do not want to poll, you can instead work with a callback-functionality. For example if you use a Swing GUI, you can have the DB thread call [invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) from the SwingUtilities class, so processing the request is done on the main Swing thread at the next possible time.

This is based on the [EventQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) class, which might be more convenient to use in certain other scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Queue, A will periodically poll the queue, B can put values to queue asynchroneously

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the post to make it more clear but I would want thread A to continue to execute normally until a response is available.

Comment: It can continue to execute. But it still needs to poll every once in a while to do something when the response is ready.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` which will return `Future` and you dont need to wait.

**Sample Usage (From java Docs on [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html))**

```
interface ArchiveSearcher { String search(String target); }
 class App {
   ExecutorService executor = ...
   ArchiveSearcher searcher = ...
   void showSearch(final String target)
       throws InterruptedException {
     Future<String> future
       = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
         public String call() {
             return searcher.search(target);
         }});
     displayOtherThings(); // do other things while searching
     try {
       displayText(future.get()); // use future
     } catch (ExecutionException ex) { cleanup(); return; }
   }
 }
```

Same can be achieved from Future task too(visit above link, example are from there only)

**The FutureTask class is an implementation of Future that implements Runnable, and so may be executed by an Executor. For example, the above construction with submit could be replaced by:**

```
 FutureTask<String> future =
       new FutureTask<String>(new Callable<String>() {
         public String call() {
           return searcher.search(target);
       }});
     executor.execute(future);
```

Comment: Why do you suggest constructing a FutureTask and passing it to Executor, while ExecutorService has a submit method, which constructs Future for you?

Comment: Well, that is not what OP wants, because the main thread will wait on `future.get()` anyway...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with executors, just create a [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) and pass it to a new thread.

```
FutureTask<String> f = new FutureTask<String>(new Callable<String>() {
    @Override
    public String call() {
        return "";
    }
});
new Thread(f).start();
while (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    if (f.isDone()) {
        System.out.println(f.get());
        break;
    }
    //do smth else
}
```

Comment: In this case the main thread will have to wait on `f.get()` which is not what OP wants

Comment: Future has isDone() method to poll if required. I don't understand your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

For thread B, declare a class that implements `Runnable`. For example:

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable
{
    private String input  = null;
    private String output = null;

    public MyClass(String input)
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public String getOutput()
    {
        return output;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        output = func(input);
    }
}
```

In thread A (which is your main thread), start thread B, and wait for it to complete **only** where you actually need its output. For example:

```
public String myFunc(String input) throws Exception
{
    MyClass object = new MyClass(input);
    Thread  thread = new Thread(object);

    thread.start();
    // Do whatever you wanna do...
    // ...
    // ...

    // And when you need the thread's output:
    thread.join();
    return object.getOutput();
}
```

Comment: The main thread will have to wait on `thread.join()` which is not what OP wants

Comment: @Adam Dyga: Thanks. But can you please review the answer again? The main thread will wait **only** when it actually needs the value. In essence, OP should call `thread.join()` just before the point where the output of that thread is **required**. Until then, the main thread continues normally without waiting for anything. I wrote `myFunc` as an example (the contents of this function can be placed anywhere within the main thread).

Answer (score 0):

Organize your main thread as an event loop:

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> eventQueue=
    new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
for (;;) {
    Runnable nextEvent=eventQueue.take();
    nextEvent.run();
}
```

Thread B:

```
Result r=fetchFromDB();
eventQueue.put(new ResultHandler(r));
```

where ResultHandler is a Runnable which knows how to handle the result.